# what does $f means in shell script?

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
Files=`(find .  -type f)`
 for f in $Files
 do
  if [ "$(dirname $f)" != "." ]
  then
  # these are files in a subdirectory
   x=$(dirname $f)  #get the name of the file with the directory
   y=${x:2}         #remove ./ from the name
   echo $(basename $f) \($y\)
  else
   # these are files in the current directory
   echo $(basename $f)
 fi
done
```

I'm having a hard time understanding what the line

```
Files=1(find . -type f)`
```

means? Is it finding each and every file in the directory? Does "type f" means finding every "file" type?
Also, What's the function of $f?

I'm starting out in shell so any help would be really helpful!

Comment: `man find` Good luck.

Comment: @shellter `man find` won't help to answer OPs question "what does $f means in shell script?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See `for f in $Files`... The `$f` referes to that `for` loop variable. It could also be written

```
Files=`(find .  -type f)`
for fred in $Files
do
  if [ "$(dirname $fred)" != "." ]
  then
  # these are files in a subdirectory
   x=$(dirname $fred)  #get the name of the file with the directory
   y=${x:2}         #remove ./ from the name
   echo $(basename $fred) \($y\)
  else
   # these are files in the current directory
   echo $(basename $fred)
 fi
done
```

And yes, `-type f` means "files".

Comment: Feel so stupid about the $f now. As for the -type f, what's the significance of . in Files=(find . -type f)?

Comment: @Laura `find` takes as argument the directory where it should start the search. It looks for things within the given directory and all subdirectories. The dot `.` in `Files=(find . -type f)` means that find should start the search "in this directory". It is the same as `./`. For instance try on your command line `cd .` and you will stay in the directory you are

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, I don't have enough reputation yet to add a comment. Elliott has the right answer regarding your 'f' variable name. To answer your follow up a question though, the significance of the period does not have anything to do with the type of file.

In linux, '.' represents your pwd or present working directory. Your pwd's parent directory is represented by '..'. The find command requires a path be supplied, whether relative or absolute. The '.' accomplishes this by effectively saying, "search in the current directory (.) and all sub-directories". Find is naturally recursive IIRC.

Happy hacking!